# Publicar aplicação Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, connectionstring

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida com Windows Form C# + Entity Framework v6.1.3, onde utilizo uma base de dados já existente.
A aplicação funciona corretamente, no Visual Studio 2013, onde estou desenvolvendo.

O meu  `App.config` possui a `ConnectionStrings` da seguinte forma:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RHContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
           connectionString="Server=SERVER;Database=BASE; 
     Trusted_Connection=false;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=USUARIO;
     Password=SENHA;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  </connectionStrings>
```

E como eu disse, funciona normalmente.

O problema é que necessito levar para ambiente de produção, ou seja, publicar.
Utilizando a opção `Publish` do próprio Visual Studio, ele gera o executável, junto com outros arquivos, que são esses:

[image: Arquivos]

E dentro da pasta `Application Files` possuo esses outros:

[image: Arquivos2]

Note, que possuo um arquivo `.condif`, porém se eu alterar a `connectionStrings` diretamente neste arquivo, recebo esse erro ao executar o `.exe`

> Não é possível baixar o aplicativo. Nem todos os arquivos exigidos pelo aplicativo estão disponíveis.

Quando eu retorno para a `connectionStrings` para a original, funciona normalmente.

Esse aplicativo, irá "rodar" em diferentes máquinas, então necessito de uma forma do técnico alterar a `connectionStrings`, não necessitando do programador.

E daí surge a minha dúvida: Como alterar a `connectionStrings` da aplicação, após publicar a mesma?

Eu pensei em criar um arquivo `txt` e ler a `connectionStrings` dele, porém não sei se é viável, ou se existe uma forma melhor de fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Ideal é você já publicar a versão com a Conexao de produção, ou, dar uma alternativa para o usuario alterar.

Mas, caso queira alterar a Connction String apos a publição, isso deve ser feito após instalar o programa... Pelo que eu ví você esta usando o ClickOnce para publicar.. Entao voce deve procurar a seguinte pasta apos a instalacao... c:\user\$NomeDoUsuario$\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\$NomeEstrano$\$OutroNomeEstranho$\ e buscar a pasta da aplicação. Achando a pasta vai ver o arquivo .config com a sua conexao..

Espero ter ajudado;

Abs.
Augusto Cordeiro

Comment: Encontrei o arquivo, e funcionou. Porém esses "nomes estranhos" serão sempre os mesmos? É que possuímos muitos clientes, e necessito documentar a forma de instalação. Ficar colocando "Nome Estranho" pegaria "mal".

Comment: A opção de criar um arquivo TXT para ler, seria inviável?

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias forma de fazer. A forma mais simples é mapear as tag connectionString em uma classe e indexa-las a partir do Windows Forms para criar a string de conexão.

Você pode fazer uma mascara utilizando String.Format e encapsular a montagem da nova string. (Fica a seu critério como você vai monta-la)

**Observação: Certifique que o contexto está apontando para string com o nome da conexão no .config nesse caso a RHContext, pois é através dela que o contexto funciona.**

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RHContext"].ConnectionString
```

Informe essa string no seu DbContext e ele ira responder mesmo se ela for alterada.

Para editar o app.config você pode utilizar a classe Configuration, segue abaixo um exemplo bem trivial:

```
public class AppConfigManager {

    //Objeto para manipular o App.config
    private static Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    #region Singleton

    private static AppConfigManager instance;

    public static AppConfigManager Configuration
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new AppConfigManager();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private AppConfigManager()
    {
        this.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString("RHContext");
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Retorna a string do App.config.
    /// </summary>
    public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// O path do arquivo de configuração de conexão
    /// </summary>
    public string ConnectionConfigPath
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.ExecutablePath + ".config";
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// A string de conexão
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetConnectionString(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw new Exception("Não foi possivel obter a conexão do nome" + key);
        }

    }      

    /// <summary>
    /// Altera a string de conexão do nome informado.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString">String a ser utilizada</param>
    public void ChangeConnectionString(string connectionString, string name)
    {
        //setando a string a ser alterada
        var cfg = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[name];

        //altera a string de conexão
        cfg.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        // Salva o que foi modificado
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        // Atualiza no app o bloco connectionStrings
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

        // Recarrega os dados de conexão
        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
    }

     /// <summary>
    /// Add uma string de conexão.
    /// MeuAppConfig é a classe onde será mapeados os atributos da connectionString
    /// </summary>
    public static void AddConnectionString(MeuAppConfig app)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(app.User))
                app.User = "";
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(app.Password))
                app.Password = "";

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = app.ServerName,
                InitialCatalog = app.Database,
                UserID = app.User,
                Password = app.Password,
                IntegratedSecurity = "False"
            };

            // add a conexão
            config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(
                new ConnectionStringSettings
                {
                    Name = app.ConnectionName,
                    ConnectionString = scsb.ConnectionString,
                    ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient"
                });

            // salva conexão
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Entrada já existe ou outro ...
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Vc também pode ler e editar o .config diretamente pelo Windows Forms. Basta mapear a tag connection da connectionString.